# TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I already read the topic that has almost the same error with me also here in stackoverflow but the solution from there isn't the fix for me. I'm new to angular js and javascript. Can someone tell me what in my code gave me this error

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
>       at TypeError (native)
>       at chrome-extension://fkdjpdbmndopefjggghlinklmkpppbfi/js/zepto.min.js:2:13781
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at HTMLUListElement. (chrome-extension://fkdjpdbmndopefjggghlinklmkpppbfi/js/zepto.min.js:2:13704)
>       at chrome-extension://fkdjpdbmndopefjggghlinklmkpppbfi/js/zepto.min.js:2:6115
>       at Object.every (native)
>       at Object.n.fn.each (chrome-extension://fkdjpdbmndopefjggghlinklmkpppbfi/js/zepto.min.js:2:6082)
>       at Object.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as append] (chrome-extension://fkdjpdbmndopefjggghlinklmkpppbfi/js/zepto.min.js:2:13575)
>       at HTMLUListElement. (chrome-extension://fkdjpdbmndopefjggghlinklmkpppbfi/js/zepto.min.js:2:9206)
>       at chrome-extension://fkdjpdbmndopefjggghlinklmkpppbfi/js/zepto.min.js:2:6115

```
$http.post('mysite.aspx',{action:'myaction',position:'position'})
      .success(function (response) 
      {
          try{
                  var htmldata='';
                  for(i=0;i<response.length;i++)
                  {
                      var htmlInfo = '<li><div class=\'col\'><a href="#"><img width=\'100%\' height=\'auto\' src="'+ response[i].Image + '" class=\'profile-img\' /><h3>' + response[i].Name +'</h3><p>'+ response[i].Position+'</p></a></div></li>';

                      htmldata+= htmlInfo;
                  }
                    $("#idOfdiv").html($sce.trustAsHtml(htmldata));
          }catch(ex)
          {
              console.log(ex);
          }
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers){
         console.log(status);
      });
```

Comment: So what browser extension do you have installed is causing the issue? Run the browser with extensions disabled. Does the error go away? If yes, start enabling them until you find which one is breaking your code.

Comment: 1. this is an unreadable mess. 
2. Although its hard to tell because of 1, this is not valid javascript code. 
3. Although its hard to tell because of 1 (again) there is no call to `.insertBefore` in the code.
Please post the relevant code and break up the 200ish character malformed string literal

Comment: @epascarello lol I didn't dig far enough into the weeds of the error message.

Comment: this isn't an extension.. this is a chrome packaged app.. i'm trying to retrieve data from a the service.. and it hits on the catch statement